# Небольшой плагин JS для оживления любого времени в верстке

Tags: javascript

Сидел-сидел, думал-думал, так и не придумал, как сделать так, что бы любое время на странице которое я вывел с помощью `PHP` превратилось в живой ОБРАТНЫЙ таймер времени (например от 5:00 до 0:00)>
Предположим у меня есть `<span id="time">3:40:30</span>` и оно должно тикать вниз до 0:00:00.
Я так и не нашел как это сделать, но думаю что это в силу своей неопытности в JS.

Comment: Сидел-сидел, читал-перечитывал, так и не понял что вы хотите))) Может есть какая-нибудь страничка-пример? Или же поподробней распишите что вы хотите.

Comment: @igolka97, вам, для начала, нужно произвести декомпозицию задачи:

1. Получение времени таймера из элемента (преобразовать строку 3:40:40 в количество секунд)
2. Запустить таймер, который каждую секунду будет
    1. Отнимать единицу от оставшегося количества секунд
    2. Обновлять значение элемента

После того, как вы это реализуете ([подсказка](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9640384), [еще подсказка](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout)), вам останется просто привязать этот функционал к каждому нужному элементу - проще всего будет повесить уникальный класс.

Comment: @Etki JS таймер крайне неаккуратен. Поэтому лучше запомнить исходное время и запускать событие скажем, каждую 1/50 секунды, где сравнивать фактическое время с исходным.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наскоро сделал jQuery плагин для обратных отсчётов: [рабочий пример](http://jsfiddle.net/sergiks/gwauk3t6/).

При запуске замеряет системное время и пускает таймер каждую 1/25 секунды. Можно и почаще сделать. По таймеру смотрим, сколько секунд прошло с запуска. Если кол-во целых секунд изменилось с последнего обновления, вписываем новое время. По окончании отсчёта заменяем время на что-то типа «Акция закончилась» – устанавливается опцией `after`.

Работает только с трёхчастным временем: `Ч:ММ:СС`. Для большей универсальности и полноценной разработки в коммерческое решение – напильник вам в руки : )

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.backtick = function( options){
        var opts = $.extend( {}, $.fn.backtick.defaults, options ),
            OO = function( n) { // добиваем числа нулём до двух позиций.
                n = n + '';
                return n.length == 1 ? '0' + n : n;
            }
        ;

        return this.each( function(){
            var device = $( this)
                ,start = device.text().split(':')
                ,start_s
                ,start_ms = (new Date()).getTime()
                ,last_s
                ,timer
            ;

            if( start.length != 3) {
                console.error('initial time format is bad');
                return false;
            }
            last_s = start_s = 3600*parseInt(start[0],10) 
                      + 60*parseInt(start[1],10)
                      + parseInt(start[2],10);

            timer = setInterval(
                function(){
                    var now = (new Date()).getTime(), S, H, M;
                    S = start_s - Math.floor( (now - start_ms) / 1E3);
                    if( last_s == S) return;  last_s = S;

                    if( S <= 0) {
                        clearInterval( timer);
                        S = 0;
                        device.text( opts.after);
                        return;
                    }
                    H = Math.floor( S / 3600); S -= H * 3600;
                    M = Math.floor( S / 60); S -= M * 60;
                    device.text( ([ H, OO(M), OO(S)]).join(':'));
                },
                opts.interval
            );
        });
    };

    // Plugin defaults
    $.fn.backtick.defaults = {
        after: "Акция закончилась", // сообщение, которым заменяется время по окончании
        interval: 40,    // время перепроверки настоящего времени, в миллисекундах
    };

})( jQuery);
```

Применение простое.   HTML:

```
<div>Таймер раз <span class="time">2:15:00</span></div>
<div>До конца тупой акции осталось <span class="time">3:00:00</span></div>
<div>До счастья <span class="time_opt">0:00:10</span></div>
```

И JavaScript:

```
$('.time').backtick();
$('.time_opt').backtick({ after: 'Счастье наступило!'});
```

Comment: Это моя первая попытка сделать плагин jQuery. Помогли их статьи:

 * [How to create a basic plugin](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)
 * [Advanced Plugin Concepts](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/advanced-plugin-concepts/)

Comment: Это самый развернутый ответ который мне когда либо давали на форумах. Спасибо

Answer (score 2):

Я бы предложил сделать как-то так (на основе http://momentjs.com)

Полный рабочий пример кода можно [посмотреть тут](http://jsfiddle.net/pvkovalev/6p59753g/)

HTML

```
<div id="now"></div>
<div id="NewYear"></div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        var now = moment();
        var then = moment('2014-12-31T23:59:59.000');
        var ms = then.diff(now, 'milliseconds', true);
        var seconds = Math.floor(moment.duration(ms).asSeconds());

        $('#NewYear').html('До Нового Года осталось: ' + seconds + ' секунд(-ы)');
        $('#now').html('сейчас ' + moment().format('HH:mm:ss'));
    }, 1000);
});
```

Надеюсь это вам поможет

Comment: @pvkovalev, "*До гового года осталось*" или всё-таки "*До Гового Нода осталось*"? ))

Comment: @Deonis это подсознание :) и отсутствие клавы с кириллицей на работе :) Спасибо, поправлю!

Comment: Счётчик уходит в минус.

Answer (score 1):

Вот небольшой скрипт под вашу задачу:
http://jsbin.com/jicurala/1/edit

```
(function () {
    // Форматирование времени
    var format = (function () {
        function num(val) {
            val = Math.floor(val);
            return val < 10 ? '0' + val : val;
        }

        return function (ms) {
            var sec = ms / 1000,
              hours = sec / 3600 % 24,
              minutes = sec / 60 % 60,
              seconds = sec % 60
            ;

            return num(hours) + ":" + num(minutes) + ":" + num(seconds);
        };
    })();

    // Получить timestamp из элемента
    var getTime = function (el) {
        if (el.ts == null) {
            var time = el.innerHTML.trim().split(':');
            el.ts = ((time[2]|0) + (time[1]|0) * 60 + (time[0]|0) * 60 * 60) * 1000;
            el.initTS = Date.now();
        }

        return el.ts - (Date.now() - el.initTS);
    };

    var timers = document.getElementsByClassName('time');
    var forEach = [].forEach;
    var initTS = Date.now();

    // Обновление времени на странице
    setInterval(function () {
        forEach.call(timers, function (el) {
            var ts = getTime(el);
            el.innerHTML = format(Math.max(ts, 0));
        });
    }, 900);
})();
```

Comment: Почему раз в 900 ms?

Comment: Потому что лень заморачивать на правильный setTimeout  c учетом запаздывания.